# How to add a hyperlink in the middle of a line with slim (without a line break)

Tags: html, ruby, slim-lang

I want to generate (using slim) the following code but all on one line.

```
li Hello world
a href="google.com" google
Goodbye
```

Right now I'm getting the hyperlink starting a new line. I've tried various things with indenting but then the link switches to plain text.

How can I get the text and hyperlink to render on a single line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can freely insert vanilla HTML tags for this purpose:

```slim
li Hello world <a href="google.com">google</a> Goodbye
```

Otherwise, there is no way to put two tags on one line. It's impossible by the very design of the language.